# SQL Server : Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have the following problem when inserting some values coming from a subquery.

I want to insert all values from this query:

```
(SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'ddMMyyyy') +'EUR'+'0' as devID , 'XXX' as dev2 from kat.[dbo].[Conversions]  LEFT  OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  'Conversions' and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 3)

What this query returns is the following data (and more rows with the following format): Columns (devID & dev2)
devID   // dev2
YYY05102017XXX0 // EUR
XXX04102017XXX0  // EUR
ZZZ03102017XXX0  // EUR

This contains the data I want to insert but when inserting into a view: I receive the following error:

Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

This is the query to insert the values:

insert into ConversionsTable( devID, dev2) values  (
(SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'ddMMyyyy') +'EUR'+'0' as devID , 'XXX' as dev2 from kat.[dbo].[Conversions]  LEFT  OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  'Conversions' and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 3))
```

Do you know where could I find the problem?

Comment: Remove the `VALUES` clause from your insert and do directly `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `VALUES` :

```
insert into ConversionsTable( devID, dev2) 
SELECT INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert (datetime,date)  ,   'ddMMyyyy') +'EUR'+'0' as devID , 'XXX' as dev2
from kat.[dbo].[Conversions] 
LEFT  OUTER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
 on (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME =  'Conversions' 
and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.ORDINAL_POSITION = 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `insert . . . select`.  However, you don't need a `left join`.

```
insert into ConversionsTable( devID, dev2)
    select cols.COLUMN_NAME + FORMAT(convert(datetime, c.date), 'ddMMyyyy') + 'EUR' + '0' as devID,
           'XXX' as dev2
    from kat.[dbo].Conversions c join
         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS cols 
         on cols.TABLE_NAME = 'Conversions' and c.ORDINAL_POSITION = 3;
```

In addition, you should include the `TABLE_SCHEMA` in your query (two tables can have the same name in different schema.